# Bright Colors in Latex

Tags: color

Is there a package that helps produce colors like the one in the picture
[image]

Comment: Do you mean `xcolor` or similar? Where exactly would you need those colors?

Answer (score 1):

Use the package `xcolor`, palettes such as `dvipsnames` or `x11names` may contain the bright colours you would like.

```
\usepackage[dvipsnames,x11names,table]{xcolor}

\usepackage{hyperref}  % style the hyperlinks
\hypersetup{
  colorlinks = true, %Colours links instead of ugly boxes
  linkcolor = RoyalBlue, %Colours links
  citecolor = ForestGreen
}
```

x11 colour names: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X11_color_names

dvips names: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Colors